# How do I setup RSpec with a gem that has an activerecord model in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

We are extracting a few models into a gem so it can be shared among a couple different services and we aren't able to get rspec running in the gem.  When we require the gemname in the spec_helper it errors saying:

```
uninitialized constant Object::ActiveRecord
```

**Some of the file contents are below. Any ideas?**

Right now the spec helper is as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  Bundler.require(:default,"test")
  require 'tup-user' # and any other gems you need
end
```

Our Gemfile is:

```
source :rubygems

# Specify your gem's dependencies in tup-user.gemspec
gemspec

gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'rails'
```

The line the error is being thrown on is the first of the class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: May I ask why the model gem (User) doesn't handle requiring ActiveRecord itself?

Comment: Great question.  Added that above the class definition and I am all set an on to the next error!  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! I'll add it as an answer so you can close the question properly. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(See comments to question) After getting some good advice on the ruby-talk mailing list, I now require any libraries a file needs within the file itself.